Give an example showing that in a real normed vector space algebraic interior points of a convex set may be different from topological interior points
Give an example showing that in a real normed vector space algebraic interior points of a convex set may be different from topological interior points.
That is to construct a real normed vector space $X$ and a convex set $C \subseteq X$, int$(C) \ne $ a-int$(C)$.
int$(C):= \{x \in C \mid \exists \ r > 0 \ s.t. O(x,r) \subseteq C)\}$.
a-int$(C):=\{ x \in C \mid \forall \ v \in X, \exists \ \varepsilon > 0 \ s.t. \forall |t| < \varepsilon, x + t v \in C \}$.
I only find an example when $C$ is not convex. Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $C=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid  x^2 + (y+1)^2 < 1 \ or \ x^2 + (y-1)^2 < 1\} \bigcup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0\}$.
Then $(0,0) \in$ a-int$(C)$, but $(0,0) \not\in \ $int$(C)$.
Can anyone give any hints? Many thanks in advance.

In many cases, you actually have $\operatorname{int}(C) = \operatorname{a-int}(C)$, i.e., if

$X$ is finite-dimensional
$X$ is complete and $C$ is closed

Thus, you need an infinite-dimensional space. I think it is more easier to consider non-complete spaces first and here I suggest $c_c$ (the space of finite sequences) equipped with some norm, e.g., the $\ell^2$ norm. Try to find a set $C$ such that $x \in C$ gives a uniform bound on $|x_n| \le c_n$ for some constants $c_n$ such that $c_n \to 0$.
